# Android Studio (0.1.6-0.2.13) non-jumbo instruction error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-build

I've encountered a problem after upgrading from Android Studio 0.1.**5** to 0.1.**6** (also from 0.1.**6** to 0.**2**.13) where my build failed with the following error:
Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index `some_number > 2^16` into a non-jumbo instruction!

I've set the following line in the `project.properties` file:
`set dex.force.jumbo=true`
(both with set and without) and this did not fix the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've fixed it by going to the Preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) ➤ Compiler and unchecking the "Use external build".
I then went to Build ➤ Rebuild Project and it worked fine.

I hope this will help someone else too.

Edit:
Please note that since Android Studio 0.2.13 (I didn't use anything between 0.2.9 and 0.2.13 so I haven't noticed when it went away) There is no "**Use external build**" option.
To overcome this issue now you need to do this:
Go to the Preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) ➤ Compiler ➤ Android Compilers and check the "**Force jumbo mode**".

Comment: but this way is going to be deprecated... so the use of the external build seems to be mandatory

Comment: You are correct. This is only a workaround until you add gradle to your project.

Comment: my project won't build as of today using the external build. I have tried the workaround adding ex.force.jumbo=true to my project.properties, but no luck.

Comment: uncheck the "use external build" or add Gradle to your project.